Reverting to the default Format definitions
Is there an easy way to clear all (user made) Format definitions?
E.g. made with
Format[s, TeXForm]:= rhs


To clarify. I don't want to clear all definitions associated to s nor do I want to by hand specify all symbols that have a Format definition attached to them.

If it is impossible to find out which definitions used Format I will instead also accept a more preventive answer that for example ensures that all future Format definitions are saved to some known token symbol rather to all the different symbols that they can be assigned to now.

$Version

(* "14.0.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (December 13, 2023)" *)

ClearAll["Global`*"]

clearFormats := (FormatValues[#] = {}) & /@
  Select[Names["Global`*"], FormatValues[#] =!= {} &]

Assign Format
Format[s, TeXForm] := rhs

Verify that s has FormatValues
FormatValues[s]

(* {HoldPattern[Format[s, TeXForm]] :> rhs} *)

Clear all formats
clearFormats;

Verify that the format is cleared
FormatValues[s]

(* {} *)


Thanks! Exactly what I needed.
